# Screensaver inhibiting executables in Windows

Tags: python, c, windows, tkinter

I made an alarm app and it's supposed to wait until a time (defined in a settings.txt file) is reached. Then it internally simulates pressing the volume keys to turn the volume all the way down, then it turns the volume up to 40. It then plays one of a collection of mp3 files that I have in a separate folder. However, I keep encountering an issue where the alarm doesn't turn the volume up high enough. It's always at 8 or 9 when I wake up. I want it to get to 40. My theory is that the fact that I turn on a screensaver at the start of runtime is messing with the program's ability to either run other programs or press the keys internally.

Here's how my program works:

1. The "Narok's Alarm.exe" file is opened, which immediately turns on a screensaver (because I'm going to sleep soon).
2. This executable waits until the time defined by settings.txt matches the current time, then it runs two other files, alarm.exe and testalarm.exe (using system()).
3. alarm.exe opens a python program called turnitdown.py, which turns the volume down to 0. Then it opens another program called turnitup.py, which turns the volume up to 40. It then opens a random mp3 file.
4. testalarm.exe opens a gui that asks the user a set of multiplication math problems. If the user gets them all right, it closes alarm.exe, Narok's Alarm, and testalarm.exe using system commands.

Here's the base program, Narok's Alarm:

```
// C implementation of digital clock
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *f;

void delay(int number_of_seconds) {

    int milli_seconds = 1000 * number_of_seconds;

    clock_t start_time = clock();

    while (clock() < start_time + milli_seconds) {
        ;
    }
}
 
// driver code
int main() {
    time_t s, val = 1;
    struct tm* current_time;

    f = fopen("settings.txt", "r");
    rewind(f);

    char place[20];
    int hour;
    int min;

    char line[40];
    int curline = 0;

    char temp[20];
    int tempa;

    while(fgets(line, 40, f) != NULL) {

        if (curline == 0) { // 1st line

            sscanf(line, "%s %d %d \n", temp, &hour, &min);
            // now you should store or manipulate those strings

            break;

        }

        curline++;

    } 
 
    // time in seconds
    s = time(NULL);
 
    // to get current time
    current_time = localtime(&s);

    system("scrnsave.scr -start");

    while (1) {
        system("TIMEOUT /T 3");
        system("cls");
        s = time(NULL);
        current_time = localtime(&s);
        if (current_time->tm_hour == hour) {
            if (current_time->tm_min == min) {

                system("start /MIN alarm.exe");
                system("start /MIN testalarm.exe");
                break;

            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's alarm.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SONGS 31

void delay(int number_of_seconds) {

    int milli_seconds = 1000 * number_of_seconds;

    clock_t start_time = clock();

    while (clock() < start_time + milli_seconds) {
    ;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    srand(time(0));
    int done = 0;
    int choice;
    char message[30];
    int wait;

    system("start /MIN turnitdown.exe");
    
    delay(10);

    system("cls");

    wait = 5;

    while (done == 0) {
        choice = (rand() % SONGS) + 1;

        switch (choice) {
            
            case 1: {
                printf("Now playing Wallace and Gromit Theme\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track1.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                printf("Now playing Connection\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track2.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                printf("Now playing Blue Morning, Blue Day\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track3.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                printf("Now playing What Kind of Hospital Is This?\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track4.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 5: {
                printf("Now playing Kickstart My Heart\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track5.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 6: {
                printf("Now playing Revolution\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track6.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 7: {
                printf("Now playing Finale of William Tell Overture\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track7.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 8: {
                printf("Now playing Finale of 1812 Overture\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track8.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 9: {
                printf("Now playing Renegade\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track9.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 10: {
                printf("Now playing Non, Je Ne Regrette Rien\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track10.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 11: {
                printf("Now playing Dream On\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track11.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 12: {
                printf("Now playing Shook Me All Night Long\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track12.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 13: {
                printf("Now playing Wake Me Up When September Ends\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track13.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 14: {
                printf("Now playing The Lion Sleeps Tonight\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track14.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 15: {
                printf("Now playing Sweet Dreams Are Made of This\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track15.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 16: {
                printf("Now playing Boulevard of Broken Dreams\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track16.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 17: {
                printf("Now playing Reveille\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track17.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 18: {
                printf("Now playing Turbo Lover\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track18.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 19: {
                printf("Now playing Holy Diver\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track19.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 20: {
                printf("Now playing Metal Health\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track20.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 21: {
                printf("Now playing Don't Fear the Reaper\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track21.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 22: {
                printf("Now playing Hold the Line\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track22.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 23: {
                printf("Now playing Shostakovich Quartet No. 8\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track23.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 24: {
                printf("Now playing Duck Tales Theme\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track24.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 25: {
                printf("Now playing Völlig Losgelöst\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track25.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 26: {
                printf("Now playing Welcome to Paradise\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track26.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 27: {
                printf("Now playing Iron Man\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track27.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 28: {
                printf("Now playing Dagothwave\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track28.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 29: {
                printf("Now playing System Shock Soundtrack L07\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track29.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 30: {
                printf("Now playing Gimme the Prize\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track30.mp3");
                break;
            }
            case 31: {
                printf("Now playing System Shock 2 Soundtrack Medsci 1\n");
                strcpy(message, "start /MIN Music/track31.mp3");
                break;
            }

        }
        
        system("start /MIN turnitup.exe");
        system(message);

        delay(210);

    }
}
```

Here's turnitup.py:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press(Key.media_volume_up)
keyboard.release(Key.media_volume_up)

time.sleep(5)

for i in range(19):
    keyboard.press(Key.media_volume_up)
    keyboard.release(Key.media_volume_up)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

testalarm.py:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import os

settings = []

f = open('settings.txt', 'r')
for lines in f:
    settings.append(str(lines))
f.close()

settings[1] = settings[1][8:]
settings[1] = int(settings[1][-3:])

settings[2] = int(settings[2][11:])

qnum = 1

num1 = 1
num2 = 1

def next():
    global qnum
    global num1
    global num2

    if (num1 * num2) == int(entry1.get()):
        if qnum == settings[1]:
            finish()
        else:
            qnum += 1
    else:
        qnum = 1

    entry1.delete(0)
    entry1.delete(0)
    entry1.delete(0)
    
    num1 = random.randint(1, settings[2])
    num2 = random.randint(1, settings[2])

    label1.config(text = f"Question {qnum}")
    label2.config(text = f"{num1} x {num2}")


def finish():
    exename = "Narok's Alarm.exe"
    os.system("taskkill /F /IM " + exename)
    os.system("taskkill /F /IM wmplayer.exe")
    os.system("taskkill /F /IM alarm.exe")
    os.system("taskkill /F /IM testalarm.exe")

root = Tk()

font1 = "Segoe UI"

num1 = random.randint(1, settings[2])
num2 = random.randint(1, settings[2])

label1 = Label(root, text = f"Question {qnum}:", font = (font1, 25))
label2 = Label(root, text = f"{num1} x {num2}", font = (font1, 25))
entry1 = Entry(root, font = (font1, 25))
button1 = Button(root, text = "Submit", command = next, font = (font1, 25))

label1.pack()
label2.pack()
entry1.pack()
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Again, my problem is that the volume for some reason never goes up to forty, it only goes up to 8 or 9. This morning it was at 9 and it made me miss class.

Thank you.

Comment: My theory is that the screensaver is messing with the button presses somehow. That didn't happen at all during testing, though. I can't think of any other explanation.

Comment: _"...and it made me miss class."_...   never rely on buggy software. :)

Comment: Do `turnitdown.py` and `turnitup.py` work as expected if you just run them manually?

Comment: Try inserting a `Sleep(ms)` into your while loop.   `while (clock() < start_time + milli_seconds;  {  Sleep(100));    }`

Comment: Your C code appears to run `turnitdown.exe` and `turnitup.exe`. Not the `.py` versions.

Comment: @pmacfarlane I used pyinstaller to make my python files into executables. The .py is just the source code.

Comment: @pmacfarlane turnitdown.exe and turnitdown.exe do work as intended when I run them on their own.

Comment: Well I don't know, your system has so many moving parts. Maybe you could simplify it. Activate the screen-saver, then do the volume increase.